# read xml by jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, xml, xml-serialization, xmlhttprequest

XML

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
        <RecentTutorials>
        <Tutorial author='The Reddest'>
        <Title>Silverlight and the Netflix API</Title>
        <Categories>
              <Category>Tutorials</Category>
              <Category>Silverlight 2.0</Category>
              <Category>Silverlight</Category>
              <Category>C#</Category>
              <Category>XAML</Category>
        </Categories>
        <Date>1/13/2009</Date>
        </Tutorial>
        </RecentTutorials>
```

Script

```
$.ajax({
   type: "post",
   url: "Default.aspx?cmd=Setting",
   success: parseXml
});
```

```
    alert(xml);//show xml File Success
    $(xml).find("Tutorial").each(function()
    {
         $("#b").append($(this).attr("author") );
    }
```

XML files have not read While alert(xml); show XML File

Answer (score 6):

Rather than `$()`, use [`$.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) to parse an XML string. (**Update:** See note below, `parseXML` was added in jQuery 1.5 but it's easy to add it to an older version if you want.) It will give you a raw XML document; you'd then use `$()` on it to get a jQuery wrapper on that doc.

Like this:

```
var xml =
    "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>" +
    "<RecentTutorials>" +
    "<Tutorial author='The Reddest'>" +
    "<Title>Silverlight and the Netflix API</Title>" +
    "<Categories>" +
    "<Category>Tutorials</Category>" +
    "<Category>Silverlight 2.0</Category>" +
    "<Category>Silverlight</Category>" +
    "<Category>C#</Category>" +
    "<Category>XAML</Category>" +
    "</Categories>" +
    "<Date>1/13/2009</Date>" +
    "</Tutorial>" +
    "</RecentTutorials>";

$($.parseXML(xml)).find("Tutorial").each(function() {
    var author = $(this).attr("author");
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/oviwo3)

If you're loading the XML via [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you typically don't have to do that as jQuery will do it for you as part of the loading sequence and then give you the XML doc as the `data` parameter to your `success` callback, but if you just have an arbitrary string and you want to parse it, `parseXML` is the tool for the job.

`ajax` example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "the/url/to/load/the/xml/from",
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(data) {
      var xdoc = $(data);    // Note that jQuery has already done the parsing for us
      display("Getting tutorials");
      var tutorials = xdoc.find("Tutorial");
      display("Found: " + tutorials.length);
      tutorials.each(function() {
          display("Tutoral author: " + $(this).attr("author"));
      });
  },
  error: function(jxhr, status, err) {
      display("Ajax error: status = " + status + ", err = " + err);
  }
});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/oviwo3/2)

---

**Update**: `parseXML` was added to jQuery in v1.5. If you can, upgrade to the latest to use it. If you can't, if you *have* to use an out-dated version, you can easily add the function to your own script. Unlike many parts of jQuery, it's nicely self-contained in the jQuery source:

```
jQuery.parseXML = function( data , xml , tmp ) {

    if ( window.DOMParser ) { // Standard
        tmp = new DOMParser();
        xml = tmp.parseFromString( data , "text/xml" );
    } else { // IE
        xml = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" );
        xml.async = "false";
        xml.loadXML( data );
    }

    tmp = xml.documentElement;

    if ( ! tmp || ! tmp.nodeName || tmp.nodeName === "parsererror" ) {
        jQuery.error( "Invalid XML: " + data );
    }

    return xml;
};
```

[Here's a live copy](http://jsbin.com/oviwo3/3) of my first example, but using jQuery 1.4.4 plus the above.

Comment: @beginner: *What* error? (Hint: When asking for help, *never* say "..but I got an error." Say "...but I got this error: ____".) As you can see from the linked example, it does work if the XML is well-formed and such (and your quoted XML is).

Comment: @beginner: I've added an `ajax` example as well.

Comment: use jquery-1.4.2.min.js  and jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js

Comment: @beginner: If you look at the link to the `parseXML` docs, you'll see it was added in v1.5. You're using v1.4.2, which is why it isn't defined. Your best bet is to use an up-to-date jQuery, but if you're stuck with 1.4.2 for some reason, see my update to the answer.

Comment: it works to me ... the matter is that i can't use find on the parsed xml. it says: "find is not a function". any tips?

Comment: @frabiacca: Recommend asking your own separate question, giving the full details, etc.