# Problem with jquery retrieving xml from asp

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, asp-classic

I tried to use jquery to get an asp-generated xml file as per [read xml by jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288457/read-xml-by-jquery) , but I get status = parsererror err = TypeError: data is null.  Entering the xml file into the browser generates a perfectly good xml file.  I hope I don't have to do a wget...

```
xmlhttp = "http://10.1.10.154:1014/dtsearch_2.asp?cmd=pdfhits&DocId=44&Index=C%3a%5cstream%5cSupport%5cIDX%5fESTATE&HitCount=4&hits=185+1ac+1d5+1ff+&hc=323&req=knife"

$.ajax({
  url: xmlhttp,
  method: "POST",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(data) {
      var xdoc = $(data);    // Note that jQuery has already done the parsing for us
      alert("Getting tutorials");
      var tutorials = xdoc.find("loc");
      alert("Found: " + tutorials.length);
      tutorials.each(function() {
          alert("Tutoral author: " + $(this).attr("pg"));
      });
  },
  error: function(jxhr, status, err) {
      alert("Ajax error: status = " + status + ", err = " + err);
  }
});
```

I use a local IP address and port 1014, but I don't see why any of that would matter...

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out the `var xdoc = $(data)` and just reference `data` directly.

```
$.ajax({
  url: xmlhttp,
  method: "POST",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(data) {
      alert("Getting tutorials");
      var tutorials = data.find("loc");
      alert("Found: " + tutorials.length);
      tutorials.each(function() {
          alert("Tutoral author: " + $(this).attr("pg"));
      });
  },
  error: function(jxhr, status, err) {
      alert("Ajax error: status = " + status + ", err = " + err);
  }
});
```

*edit*

This falls under the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). If you need it to be on a separate port you will want to look into using JSONP.

**note**

> As of jQuery 1.5, jQuery can convert a dataType from what it received in the Content-Type header to what you require. For example, if you want a text response to be treated as XML, use "text xml" for the dataType. You can also make a JSONP request, have it received as text, and interpreted by jQuery as XML: "jsonp text xml." Similarly, a shorthand string such as "jsonp xml" will first attempt to convert from jsonp to xml, and, failing that, convert from jsonp to text, and then from text to xml.

```
$.ajax({
    url: xmlhttp,
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp xml',
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Getting tutorials');
        var tutorials = data.find('loc');
        alert('Found: ' + tutorials.length);
        tutorials.each(function() {
            alert('Tutorial author: ' + $(this).attr('pg'));
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Ajax error: status = ' + status + ', err = ' + err);
    }
});
```

*reference* http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: nah, data is null.  When I firebug it, I get no response, but XML is 
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{1ab824d6-817a-4c37-8256-893e5da80577} Line Number 1, Column 1:

^

Comment: Can you post your XML? Trying to re-create but I cannot access the XML file.

Comment: Figured it out. It's the port.  Can you not specify a port with ajax?

Comment: No, it falls under the https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript, If you need to do it on a separate port you should look into JSONP, I updated my answer.